# Multiple update with division

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my code:

```
update Market 
set VatCodeID =(select  VATValue from Market) / (select  TotalValue from Market)
```

I get error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Also i want to make Round(VatcodeID,0) at the same time

Comment: What is the datatype for the columns `VATValue` and `TotalValue`?

Comment: The datatype its float

Answer (score 2):

You are using two sub-queries here:

```
(select  VATValue from Market) / (select  TotalValue from Market)
```

Try to mark them separartely and run them.

```
select  VATValue from Market;
select  TotalValue from Market;
```

You will get more than one result. SQL is complaining because it can not to a division with result sets...

You mast get sure, that both your sub-selects return just one value...

### UPDATE

Might be, that your query should be this:

```
update Market set VatCodeID =VATValue/TotalValue;
```

As your sub-selects query the same table, you maybe just want to use values of the same row...

### UPDATE Example

```
DECLARE @market TABLE(VATCodeID FLOAT,VATValue FLOAT,TotalValue FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @market VALUES
 (1,2,3)
,(1,11.5,3.1)
,(1,33.7777,(10.0/3.0));

SELECT * FROM @market;

UPDATE @market SET VATCodeID=ROUND(VATValue/TotalValue,0);

SELECT *
      ,VATValue/TotalValue AS CheckWithThisValue
FROM @market
```

The result

```
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+
| VATCodeID | VATValue | TotalValue | CheckWithThisValue |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+
| 1         | 2        | 3          | 0,666666666666667  |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+
| 4         | 11,5     | 3,1        | 3,70967741935484   |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+
| 10        | 33,7777  | 3,333333   | 10,1333110133311   |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I want to make the update for each one row separately

Comment: Thank you! Is is making Round at the same time? update Market set Round(VatCodeID,0) = VATValue  /  TotalValue

Comment: @DiH, no, but you can just apply the function with `update Market set VatCodeID =ROUND(VATValue/TotalValue,0);`. See some details [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/round.php)